# Beyond WKB approximation for energies

Tags: semiclassical

In the first term the energies are given by the Wentzel–Kramers–Brillouin (WKB) formula

$$ \oint p  dq = 2\pi  \left( n+\frac{1}{2} \right) $$

However, can this formula be improved to include further corrections? For example the wave function in the WKB approach can be evaluated to several orders of magnitude in $ \hbar $

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Brillouin%E2%80%93Keller_method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the following, I'll describe to you how in principle one can compute higher order corrections to the Bohr-Sommerfeld condition.
In order to find higher order corrections to the Bohr-Sommerfeld formula, we need to include higher order corrections of the wavefunction of the form:
$$
\Psi(x) = \sum_n \hbar^n a_n(x) \exp\left(\frac{i}{\hbar} \int^x \sqrt{2m(E-V(y)) }dy\right)\,.
$$
Inserting in the Schrodinger equation and requiring fullfilment to each
order of $\hbar$, we obtain:
$$
a_0 = \frac{const.}{(2m(E-V(y)))^{\frac{1}{4}} }
$$
and
$$
a_k \Delta S + 2  \nabla a_k\cdot \nabla S = i \Delta a_{k-1}\,,
$$
where
$$ S= \int^x \sqrt{2m(E-V(y)) } dy\,.
$$
In one dimension these equations can solved in closed form.

The quantization condition is achieved through the requirement that the wave function phase does not change over a closed loop:
$$
\oint^x \frac{1}{\Psi} \frac{d\Psi}{dx} dx = 2\pi i n\hbar\,.
$$
Please see, the following [article](http://ipht.cea.fr/Docspht/articles/t89/127/public/publi.pdf) by A. Voros where this procedure was
applied to the anharmonic oscillator. Equation (4.4), describes an
explicit solution of the wave function to the first higher order.

Remark: Voros uses the Bargmann representation of the phase space instead of the usual coordinate-momentum representation.

Comment: have you got a good, accessible reference for the Bargmann representation? I remember having trouble finding one last time round.

Comment: @Emilio You may find these lecture note by B.C. Hall useful: http://www.math.cinvestav.mx/~NorteSur/Taller10/notas/Hall.pdf